# How to save time type data in different format in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to know when I am trying to save time type data, for example in this format: yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss, can I only save this data in text type in Apache IoTDB? Or how can I save it in different format in IoTDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the data type before you saved it in Apache IoTDB, such as directly converting it to a Linux timestamp, or even set a initial value yourself, and then only save the offset amount in IoTDB.